# Windows Right-Click copy vs Powershell Copy-Item

Tags: windows, powershell, clipboard, powershell-4.0, robocopy

I want to copy a directory containing log files, but my script is timing out when using powershell to perform the copy. If I simply right-click the log directory and copy it, it works fine.

```
Copy-Item -Path "$logpath" -Destination "$archivepath" -Recurse
```

The log directory is actively being written to which is what is causing the time-out. How can I copy this directory with powershell? I can copy it using Right-click but I can't with powershell.

Comment: Have you considered using robocopy? It's specially made for copy jobs.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Olaf. robocopy is flat out the fastest and most flexible copy option for anything big or with lots of files. I've seen so many people try to replicate it with other tools, including PowerShell, but 99% of the time they'd be better off just using robocopy.

Comment: If I copy to clipboard using powershell 5 i can do the copy. But im running powershell 4 on this specific server. Let me try robocopy.

Comment: Robocopy worked. Using the following to suppress output `Robocopy.exe "$logpath" "$backuppath" /E | Out-Null` I was gonna go through upgrading powershell but this is easier and its working.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Powershell v5**

```
$logpath="C:\Path\To\LogDir"
$backuppath="C:\Path\To\BackupDir"

Set-Clipboard -Path "$logpath"
Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList | Copy-Item -Destination "$backuppath" -Recurse
```

**Using Robocopy**

```
Robocopy.exe "$logpath" "$backuppath" /E | Out-Null
```